# Edits from deleted users don't display normally

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

While browsing the site, I ran across [this slightly odd-looking answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/37058/1980):

[image: double signature]

Normally, when a user edits their own post, the full signature isn't duplicated, so I looked at the [revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/37058/revisions) and found that the most recent (and only) edit to the post had been [suggested](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2247) by a now-deleted user:

[image: edit from deleted user]

I'm only guessing that it's the user's deletion which is causing the double signature, but whatever the cause, I'm guessing this isn't intended behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in the next build of the site.

See [When the last editor is deleted, the gravatar of a previous editor is shown instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/when-the-last-editor-is-deleted-the-gravatar-of-a-previous-editor-is-shown-inst/117502#117502) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

It's a known bug that's been reported in the past, but it is currently low priority in fixing.